# Creating hash value from multiple columns

Tags: sql, hash, amazon-redshift, md5

I have an example product sales table which consists of around 15 columns and a couple thousand rows. The columns I'm most interested in look like this:

```
product_type     currency    amount    order_time               delivered_time
hoodie           GBP         60.0      2021-03-10  14:32:07     2021-03-13  16:05:52
shirt            EUR         30.0      2021-03-20  19:22:32     2021-03-24  11:18:46
...
```

There currently is a unique identifier but it isn't useful for broad analysis, there can be multiple products in an order but they'd all have a different identifier so you can't match them up.

What i want to do is create a new identifier column using a hash function, I've used the below code and showed an example output of what I get:

```
SELECT *, Md5(product_type||currency||amount)
FROM sales

product_type     currency    amount   identifier   
Coat             GBP         100.0    825be52c31f1d92584720466d743e2cf
Coat             GBP         100.0    825be52c31f1d92584720466d743e2cf
```

This code works for the 3 columns that I've included in the hash function, but I also want to include the two DATETIME columns into the function but it doesn't work. I've used this code to try include them, the code runs but the hash values i get are completed different to each other even if all the values in the columns match up:

```
SELECT *, Md5(product_type||currency||amount||TRUNC(order_time)||TRUNC(delivered_time))
```

I've used the TRUNC function on the two date columns as I'm not too concerned about the exact minutes or seconds, mainly interested in just the date itself. How could I include the two datetime columns without it messing up the hash function?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Are you getting an error?

Comment: no, it runs but the hash value is different even if all the values in that row match up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` instead of TRUNC()

```
 Md5(product_type||currency||amount||to_char(order_time,'YYYY-MM-DD')||to_char(delivered_time,'YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

Or if the datatype is string/varchar, use SUBSTRING(date,1,10)

```
Md5(product_type||currency||amount||SUBSTRING(order_time,1,10)||SUBSTRING(delivered_time,1,10))
```